# Remove Windows Explorer Drop Down Options

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

I am trying to lock down a Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal server.

At the moment, when a user opens a directory, there is the option in the Windows Explorer address bar to choose locations. In the root (most left hand side drop down) of this is 'Desktop' and 'User Profile' directory.

Does anyone know - most likely through registry I guess - how I can remove these 2 entries from the drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing these links entirely, you may wish to use **[folder redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx)** and redirect them to the user's home directory on the corporate network.

See also:

- [User profile configuration options for Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/02/user-profiles-on-windows-server-2008-r2-remote-desktop-services.aspx)